# Building package on Windows 10: "Warning: On Windows, creating file symlinks requires Administrator privileges"

Tags: build, package, installation, julia

I want to install packages on Windows 10 at work for `Julia 1.3`. I asked a similar question there and could solve it by getting Administrator Privilege and deactivating the firewall. Now because I wanted to install `GLM`, the following message appeared:

```
ERROR: LoadError: No deps.jl file could be found. Please try running Pkg.build("Arpack").
Currently, the build command might fail when Julia has been built from source
and the recommendation is to use the official binaries from julialang.org.
For more info see https://github.com/JuliaLinearAlgebra/Arpack.jl/issues/5.
```

So I tried to the command `Pkg.build("Arpack")`:

```
  Building Arpack → `C:\Users\*******\.julia\packages\Arpack\cu5By\deps\build.log`
┌ Error: Error building `Arpack`: 
│ ┌ Warning: On Windows, creating file symlinks requires Administrator privileges
│ └ @ Base.Filesystem file.jl:848
│ [ Info: Downloading https://github.com/JuliaLinearAlgebra/ArpackBuilder/releases/download/v3.5.0-3/Arpack.v3.5.0-3.x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc7.tar.gz to C:\Users\*******\.julia\packages\Arpack\cu5By\deps\usr\downloads\Arpack.v3.5.0-3.x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc7.tar.gz...
│ ERROR: LoadError: Could not download https://github.com/JuliaLinearAlgebra/ArpackBuilder/releases/download/v3.5.0-3/Arpack.v3.5.0-3.x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc7.tar.gz to C:\Users\*******\.julia\packages\Arpack\cu5By\deps\usr\downloads\Arpack.v3.5.0-3.x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc7.tar.gz:
│ ErrorException("")
│ Stacktrace:
│  [1] error(::String) at .\error.jl:33
│  [2] #download#93(::Bool, ::typeof(BinaryProvider.download), ::String, ::String) at C:\Users\*******\.julia\packages\BinaryProvider\kcGxO\src\PlatformEngines.jl:502
│  [3] #download at .\none:0 [inlined]
│  [4] #download_verify#94(::Bool, ::Bool, ::Bool, ::typeof(download_verify), ::String, ::String, ::String) at C:\Users\*******\.julia\packages\BinaryProvider\kcGxO\src\PlatformEngines.jl:571
│  [5] #download_verify at .\tuple.jl:0 [inlined]
│  [6] #install#133(::Prefix, ::String, ::Bool, ::Bool, ::Bool, ::typeof(install), ::String, ::String) at C:\Users\*******\.julia\packages\BinaryProvider\kcGxO\src\Prefix.jl:314
│  [7] (::BinaryProvider.var"#kw##install")(::NamedTuple{(:prefix, :force, :verbose),Tuple{Prefix,Bool,Bool}}, ::typeof(install), ::String, ::String) at .\tuple.jl:0
│  [8] top-level scope at C:\Users\*******\.julia\packages\Arpack\cu5By\deps\build.jl:70
│  [9] include at .\boot.jl:328 [inlined]
│  [10] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at .\loading.jl:1105
│  [11] include(::Module, ::String) at .\Base.jl:31
│  [12] include(::String) at .\client.jl:424
│  [13] top-level scope at none:5
│ in expression starting at C:\Users\*******\.julia\packages\Arpack\cu5By\deps\build.jl:68
│ caused by [exception 2]
│ 
│ Stacktrace:
│  [1] error() at .\error.jl:42
│  [2] #download#93(::Bool, ::typeof(BinaryProvider.download), ::String, ::String) at C:\Users\*******\.julia\packages\BinaryProvider\kcGxO\src\PlatformEngines.jl:496
│  [3] #download at .\none:0 [inlined]
│  [4] #download_verify#94(::Bool, ::Bool, ::Bool, ::typeof(download_verify), ::String, ::String, ::String) at C:\Users\*******\.julia\packages\BinaryProvider\kcGxO\src\PlatformEngines.jl:571
│  [5] #download_verify at .\tuple.jl:0 [inlined]
│  [6] #install#133(::Prefix, ::String, ::Bool, ::Bool, ::Bool, ::typeof(install), ::String, ::String) at C:\Users\*******\.julia\packages\BinaryProvider\kcGxO\src\Prefix.jl:314
│  [7] (::BinaryProvider.var"#kw##install")(::NamedTuple{(:prefix, :force, :verbose),Tuple{Prefix,Bool,Bool}}, ::typeof(install), ::String, ::String) at .\tuple.jl:0
│  [8] top-level scope at C:\Users\*******\.julia\packages\Arpack\cu5By\deps\build.jl:70
│  [9] include at .\boot.jl:328 [inlined]
│  [10] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at .\loading.jl:1105
│  [11] include(::Module, ::String) at .\Base.jl:31
│  [12] include(::String) at .\client.jl:424
│  [13] top-level scope at none:5
│ caused by [exception 1]
│ IOError: symlink: operation not permitted (EPERM)
│ Stacktrace:
│  [1] uv_error at .\libuv.jl:97 [inlined]
│  [2] symlink(::String, ::String) at .\file.jl:851
│  [3] probe_symlink_creation(::String) at C:\Users\*******\.julia\packages\BinaryProvider\kcGxO\src\PlatformEngines.jl:121
│  [4] #probe_platform_engines!#30(::Bool, ::typeof(BinaryProvider.probe_platform_engines!)) at C:\Users\*******\.julia\packages\BinaryProvider\kcGxO\src\PlatformEngines.jl:175
│  [5] probe_platform_engines! at C:\Users\*******\.julia\packages\BinaryProvider\kcGxO\src\PlatformEngines.jl:169 [inlined]
│  [6] __init__() at C:\Users\*******\.julia\packages\BinaryProvider\kcGxO\src\BinaryProvider.jl:28
│  [7] _include_from_serialized(::String, ::Array{Any,1}) at .\loading.jl:692
│  [8] _require_search_from_serialized(::Base.PkgId, ::String) at .\loading.jl:776
│  [9] _require(::Base.PkgId) at .\loading.jl:1001
│  [10] require(::Base.PkgId) at .\loading.jl:922
│  [11] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at .\loading.jl:917
│  [12] include at .\boot.jl:328 [inlined]
│  [13] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at .\loading.jl:1105
│  [14] include(::Module, ::String) at .\Base.jl:31
│  [15] include(::String) at .\client.jl:424
│  [16] top-level scope at none:5
│ Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy 
│ Authentication Required."
│ At line:5 char:1
│ + $webclient.DownloadFile("https://github.com/JuliaLinearAlgebra/Arpack ...
│ + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
│     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
│     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
│  
└ @ Pkg.Operations D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.3
```

**EDIT**

After reading https://github.com/JuliaLinearAlgebra/Arpack.jl/issues/5. and related links, I tried to downgrade to Julia 1.0.5 and tried to install packages and run into same Kind of trouble:

```
julia> Pkg.add("IJulia")
  Updating registry at `C:\Users\*******\.julia\registries\General`
  Updating git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git`
┌ Warning: Some registries failed to update:
│     — C:\Users\*******\.julia\registries\General — failed to fetch from repo
└ @ Pkg.API C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\API.jl:162
 Resolving package versions...
  Updating `C:\Users\*******\.julia\environments\v1.0\Project.toml`
 [no changes]
  Updating `C:\Users\*******\.julia\environments\v1.0\Manifest.toml`
 [no changes]

julia> using IJulia
[ Info: Precompiling IJulia [7073ff75-c697-5162-941a-fcdaad2a7d2a]
ERROR: LoadError: MbedTLS not installed properly, run Pkg.build("MbedTLS"), restart Julia and try again
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at .\error.jl:33
 [2] top-level scope at C:\Users\*******\.julia\packages\MbedTLS\X4xar\src\MbedTLS.jl:43
 [3] include at .\boot.jl:317 [inlined]
 [4] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at .\loading.jl:1044
 [5] include(::Module, ::String) at .\sysimg.jl:29
 [6] top-level scope at none:2
 [7] eval at .\boot.jl:319 [inlined]
 [8] eval(::Expr) at .\client.jl:393
 [9] top-level scope at .\none:3
in expression starting at C:\Users\*******\.julia\packages\MbedTLS\X4xar\src\MbedTLS.jl:42
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: Failed to precompile MbedTLS [739be429-bea8-5141-9913-cc70e7f3736d] to C:\Users\*******\.julia\compiled\v1.0\MbedTLS\bf9T0.ji.
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at .\error.jl:33
 [2] compilecache(::Base.PkgId, ::String) at .\loading.jl:1203
 [3] _require(::Base.PkgId) at .\loading.jl:960
 [4] require(::Base.PkgId) at .\loading.jl:858
 [5] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at .\loading.jl:853
 [6] include at .\boot.jl:317 [inlined]
 [7] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at .\loading.jl:1044
 [8] include at .\sysimg.jl:29 [inlined]
 [9] include(::String) at C:\Users\*******\.julia\packages\IJulia\F1GUo\src\IJulia.jl:33
 [10] top-level scope at none:0
 [11] include at .\boot.jl:317 [inlined]
 [12] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at .\loading.jl:1044
 [13] include(::Module, ::String) at .\sysimg.jl:29
 [14] top-level scope at none:2
 [15] eval at .\boot.jl:319 [inlined]
 [16] eval(::Expr) at .\client.jl:393
 [17] top-level scope at .\none:3
in expression starting at C:\Users\*******\.julia\packages\IJulia\F1GUo\src\hmac.jl:1
in expression starting at C:\Users\*******\.julia\packages\IJulia\F1GUo\src\IJulia.jl:305
ERROR: Failed to precompile IJulia [7073ff75-c697-5162-941a-fcdaad2a7d2a] to C:\Users\*******\.julia\compiled\v1.0\IJulia\nfu7T.ji.
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at .\error.jl:33
 [2] compilecache(::Base.PkgId, ::String) at .\loading.jl:1203
 [3] _require(::Base.PkgId) at .\loading.jl:960
 [4] require(::Base.PkgId) at .\loading.jl:858
 [5] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at .\loading.jl:853


Pkg.build("MbedTLS")
  Building MbedTLS → `C:\Users\*******\.julia\packages\MbedTLS\X4xar\deps\build.log`
┌ Error: Error building `MbedTLS`:
│ ┌ Warning: On Windows, creating file symlinks requires Administrator privileges
│ └ @ Base.Filesystem file.jl:794
│ ┌ Warning: platform_key() is deprecated, use platform_key_abi() from now on
│ │   caller = ip:0x0
│ └ @ Core :-1
│ [ Info: Downloading https://github.com/JuliaWeb/MbedTLSBuilder/releases/download/v0.16.0/MbedTLS.v2.13.1.x86_64-w64-mingw32.tar.gz to C:\Users\*******\.julia\packages\MbedTLS\X4xar\deps\usr\downloads\MbedTLS.v2.13.1.x86_64-w64-mingw32.tar.gz...
│ ERROR: LoadError: Could not download https://github.com/JuliaWeb/MbedTLSBuilder/releases/download/v0.16.0/MbedTLS.v2.13.1.x86_64-w64-mingw32.tar.gz to C:\Users\*******\.julia\packages\MbedTLS\X4xar\deps\usr\downloads\MbedTLS.v2.13.1.x86_64-w64-mingw32.tar.gz:
│ ErrorException("")
│ Stacktrace:
│  [1] error(::String) at .\error.jl:33
│  [2] #download#93(::Bool, ::Function, ::String, ::String) at C:\Users\*******\.julia\packages\BinaryProvider\kcGxO\src\PlatformEngines.jl:502
│  [3] #download at .\none:0 [inlined]
│  [4] #download_verify#94(::Bool, ::Bool, ::Bool, ::Function, ::String, ::String, ::String) at C:\Users\*******\.julia\packages\BinaryProvider\kcGxO\src\PlatformEngines.jl:571
│  [5] #download_verify at .\none:0 [inlined]
│  [6] #install#133(::Prefix, ::String, ::Bool, ::Bool, ::Bool, ::Function, ::String, ::String) at C:\Users\*******\.julia\packages\BinaryProvider\kcGxO\src\Prefix.jl:314
│  [7] (::getfield(BinaryProvider, Symbol("#kw##install")))(::NamedTuple{(:prefix, :force, :verbose),Tuple{Prefix,Bool,Bool}}, ::typeof(install), ::String, ::String) at .\none:0
│  [8] top-level scope at C:\Users\*******\.julia\packages\MbedTLS\X4xar\deps\build.jl:48
│  [9] include at .\boot.jl:317 [inlined]
│  [10] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at .\loading.jl:1044
│  [11] include(::Module, ::String) at .\sysimg.jl:29
│  [12] include(::String) at .\client.jl:392
│  [13] top-level scope at none:0
│ in expression starting at C:\Users\*******\.julia\packages\MbedTLS\X4xar\deps\build.jl:44
│ Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required."
│ At line:5 char:1
│ + $webclient.DownloadFile("https://github.com/JuliaWeb/MbedTLSBuilder/r ...
│ + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
│     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
│     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
│
└ @ Pkg.Operations C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\Operations.jl:1096
```

**EDIT 2**

I then tried the following (posted by @staticfloat): but still got an error message

```
(v1.3) pkg> add https://github.com/JuliaLinearAlgebra/Arpack.jl#sf/update_arpack_tarball
  Updating registry at `C:\Users\i0310451\.julia\registries\General`
  Updating git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git`
┌ Warning: Some registries failed to update:
│     — C:\Users\i0310451\.julia\registries\General — failed to fetch from repo
└ @ Pkg.Types D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.3\Pkg\src\Types.jl:1199
   Cloning git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaLinearAlgebra/Arpack.jl`
ERROR: failed to clone from https://github.com/JuliaLinearAlgebra/Arpack.jl, error: GitError(Code:ERROR, Class:OS, failed to send request: The operation timed out
)
```

Comment: Not really answering your question, but you might be able to use [KrylovKit.jl](https://github.com/Jutho/KrylovKit.jl) instead which is written purely in Julia and therefore has no binary dependencies, like Arpack.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @crstnbr. But if the final goal is to use `GLM` which needs `Arpack`, I will still not be able to use `GLM` right?

Comment: So just for the record, @crtnbr, I did install `KrylovKit.jl` without problem, but the problem upon installing `GLM` did unfurtonatly persist indeed.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the `Arpack.jl` package using an old tarball that has symlinks embedded within it; more modern Julia packages are now much more careful about generating tarballs with symlinks within them [1], as many Windows installations cannot extract them.

There is [a PR open against `Arpack.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaLinearAlgebra/Arpack.jl/pull/82) to fix this, I imagine it will be merged within the next day or two, and a new release cut immediately afterward.  However, if you wish to use it immediately, you can run `pkg> add https://github.com/JuliaLinearAlgebra/Arpack.jl#sf/update_arpack_tarball` to get the fixes locally immediately.  Note that by running that you lock yourself to that version until you either `free` or `rm` the `Arpack` dependency in whatever project you're working inside of.

[1] Modern versions of [`BinaryBuilder.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaPackaging/BinaryBuilder.jl), the binary building crosscompiler infrastructure that much of the ecosystem uses, has [many audit passes](https://github.com/JuliaPackaging/BinaryBuilder.jl/blob/master/src/Auditor.jl) that it uses to inspect binary dependencies, including things like [collapsing symlinks within windows-targeted tarballs](https://github.com/JuliaPackaging/BinaryBuilder.jl/blob/master/src/Auditor.jl#L153-L165).

Comment: Many for your answer @staticfloat. I to run `pkg> add https://github.com/JuliaLinearAlgebra/Arpack.jl#sf/update_arpack_tarball` but unfortunately still got an error which I posted in the question as an edit.

Comment: Your error sounds like a network problem; it says the request timed out.  Do you have a special network setup where you need to use proxies or you have firewalls or something else you need to disable?

Comment: Thanks again for your time @staticfloat. Well I tried to get rid of the firewall by deactivating the firewall, giving me administrator privileges to install softwares and restarted the computer. However, there maybe another layer of firewall or something that I'm not aware of...

Comment: It may be that the `https://github.com` URL that the `pkg> add` command is attempting to use is downloading things in a way that you don't normally get commands.  The simplest thing to do is probably to wait for a new release of `Arpack.jl` to be cut, then just `pkg> upgrade`, and you'll get the version that has the new symlink-free tarballs.  This should be available in a day or two at the latest.